# Has gnu(2048) been found?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

The gnu (or Group NUmber) function describes how many groups there are of a given order. The number of groups of each order are known up to 2047, see https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf
Has any progress been made on the number of groups of order 2048? This case is particularly difficult due to 2048 being a large power of 2. It is known that the number of groups of order 2048 of nilpotency class 2 is 1,774,274,116,992,170 (according to the above link), and apparently the full group number is expected to agree with this number in the first three digits.

Comment: I didn't realise that this was [the very first OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A000001)!  Also, though surely anyone already here will know it, a good time to advertise to anyone who doesn't know how many 2-groups there are that [99.15% of the groups of order $\le 2000$ have order $1024$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241369/more-than-99-of-groups-of-order-less-than-2000-are-of-order-1024).

Comment: @thomas not to be a nag, but is there something unsatisfying about my answer, since you haven't accepted it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No, it is unknown, and I don't think we will find it anytime soon. For the state of the art, see our 2017 paper "Constructing groups of ‘small’ order: Recent results and open problems" [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-70566-8_8) (here is a [PDF](https://www.quendi.de/data/papers/EHH2018-small-groups.pdf)). I collected the known data on [a little website](http://groups.quendi.de/) for easier browsing. And am working as I type this on packaging it up for GAP.